# tesseract `nobatch box.train` FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract 3.0.5 for training Chinese.

First, I use `tesseract chi.font.exp0.tif chi.font.exp0 -l chi_sim batch.nochop makebox`, I get the chi.font.exp0.box.

Second, I edit the tif whit jTessBoxEditor, add boxes around Chinese characters unrecognized by tesseract.

Then I use `tesseract chi.font.exp0.tif chi.font.exp0 nobatch box.train`, but all the boxes I added manually are not matched.

> FAIL! APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 431/汐 ((252,520),(282,550)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
>
> FAIL! APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 432/汛 ((286,520),(316,550)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob

But my boxes are right in the place around every character. So what's the problem?